# Which GPIO pins are used for I2S audio I/O

Tags: gpio, audio, i2s

I am trying to set up the ADAU1781 as an audio codec for the Pi 3 B, communicating with the Pi via the GPIO pins. Which pins would I use for I2S audio input and output? I have been doing a lot of research on the subject and cannot seem to find a clear answer to the question. Would it be the TXD0 and RXD0 or is it one of the GPIO_GEN pins as set up by the driver?

Comment: Everything I've read about i2s on pi involves the [P5 connector](http://www.runeaudio.com/forum/i2s-dac-gpio-pins-on-p5-t359.html)

Comment: I have read this as well, however the P5 connector is only present (at least with that name) on the Pi 1. 2 and 3 feature a different layout for GPIO. Does anyone know what the Pi 3 equivalent would be?

Comment: Sorry for the misdirection - all i2s schematics I've seen for PiB+ and 2/3 use GPIOs 18,19,20,21 for i2s

Comment: Thats great to know, thanks so much for your help! Could you share some links to the schematics? I think looking at those would help answer a lot of my questions.